# Optimizing a numpy array creation

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

I want to optimize my code. A huge bottleneck is in the creation of a kind of small numpy array (repeated a large number of times). Now, I cannot avoid the number of calls to that function (in my case millions of calls). I cannot vectorize all these calls together as they are unfortunately subsequent by definition of the problem (they are generated within a Newton solver at each independent inner loops). So my goal is to reduce the time taken to create that matrix in each iteration. Even a small gain would have large repercussions in the end.

```
def compute_matrix(a, my_dict):
    m = np.zeros(a, a)
    m[0][0] = my_dict['value00']
    m[0][1] = my_dict['value01']
    m[1][1] = my_dict['value11']
    m[1][3] = my_dict['value13']
    m[1][4] = my_dict['value14']
    # ... The array is very sparse, but not banded or with any regular pattern, see below for an example with values
    m[34][35] = my_dict['value3435']
```

Note that I simplified the example, in reality, it looks like:

```
m[idx['val0']][idx['val0']] = my_dict['val0']['value_a']
m[idx['val0']][idx['val1']] = my_dict['val0']['value_b']
```

where idx is a dictionary linking the 'val0' to its index in the (square) array, here for example, idx['val0'] = 0 and idx['val1'] = 1.

What would you suggest as the best strategies (multiple strategies welcome, I want to optimize the hell out of this as it's the single biggest bottleneck I have in which I drop 60% of my time!).

My main thought is to use Cython/Numba for that function, depending on the ease of each (probably Cython). I have in the past optimized code by using the C-API, but I don't see how it would really apply here due to the numpy object, and anyway the overhead would potentially be too high, as the array is pretty small (~40*40).

The non-zero values in the array will change, but the zeros will always remain zeros. Maybe something doable using this property?

Is there a low hanging optimization fruit you could see here, or is Cython my only real option? Or is Cython not even likely to help much at all?

An example of the end matrix:

```
[[-6.3e-10     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0     1.7e-11     0     6.5e-10     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0   ]
 [    0    -3.4e-06     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0     8.0e-10  4.9e-04     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0   ]
 [    0        0    -4.0e-09  9.7e-13     0        0        0        0        0        0     4.9e-08     0        0        0        0        0        0        0     3.8e-06     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0   ]
 [    0     3.4e-06  1.3e-09 -4.9e-09  8.9e-13     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0   ]
 [    0        0        0     7.2e-10 -1.8e-09  5.3e-12     0        0        0        0        0        0     1.2e-09     0        0        0        0        0        0        0     1.9e-04     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0   ]
 [    0        0        0        0     9.0e-10 -7.6e-09  1.7e-12     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0   ]
 [    0        0        0        0        0     7.9e-10 -6.4e-10     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0     2.1e-06     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0   ]
 [    0        0        0        0        0     1.5e-09     0    -4.1e-09  1.3e-12     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0     1.5e-12     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0   ]
 [    0        0        0        0        0        0        0     5.5e-10 -8.1e-09  1.6e-13     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0   ]
 [    0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0     9.1e-10 -3.2e-09     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0     7.0e-10  5.9e-12  5.9e-12     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0   ]
 [    0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0    -5.0e-08  9.1e-13     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0     9.9e-06     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0   ]
 [    0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0     4.2e-10 -7.1e-09  5.9e-13     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0   ]
 [    0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0     1.0e-09 -3.5e-09  2.0e-12     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0     1.9e-05  4.4e-04     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0   ]
 [    0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0     1.3e-09 -6.8e-09  1.5e-12     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0   ]
 [    0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0     1.0e-09 -6.7e-10     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0   ]
 [    0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0    -5.0e-09  1.8e-12     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0   ]
 [    0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0     9.8e-10 -1.0e-09     0        0        0        0     1.1e-11     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0   ]
 [    0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0    -3.7e-09  3.3e-12     0        0     1.2e-06     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0   ]
 [    0     2.4e-12     0        0        0        0        0        0     7.2e-13     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0     2.9e-09 -3.8e-06     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0   ]
 [ 5.4e-10     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0    -4.9e-04     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0   ]
 [    0     3.3e-09     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0     1.1e-09 -1.9e-04     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0   ]
 [ 4.2e-12     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0     7.8e-10     0        0        0        0    -1.2e-06     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0   ]
 [    0        0        0        0        0        0        0     2.9e-09  1.6e-10  3.3e-13     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0    -1.2e-05     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0   ]
 [    0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0     2.9e-10     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0    -1.9e-05     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0   ]
 [    0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0     2.4e-09     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0    -4.4e-04     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0   ]
 [ 5.8e-12  7.9e-11  1.8e-10  2.7e-10  6.0e-11  3.5e-10  4.1e-11  4.1e-11  4.6e-10  3.0e-11  2.4e-11  3.9e-10  6.6e-11  3.8e-10  4.3e-11  2.6e-10  1.4e-11  5.3e-11  3.0e-10  9.0e-11     0     9.5e-11  4.4e-10  4.5e-10  4.5e-10     0     3.0e-01  1.2e+00  9.8e-01  9.5e-02  3.5e+00  2.6e-02  4.1e-02  2.7e-05  3.5e+00  4.0e-04  7.0e-03  4.2e-03]
 [ 8.4e-13     0     2.7e-12  5.7e-12  1.7e-12  1.8e-11  2.1e-12  5.7e-13     0     7.7e-13  1.6e-13     0        0     8.0e-12     0     1.4e-11  1.1e-12  1.9e-12  1.5e-11  1.0e-11     0     1.1e-11     0        0        0        0    -3.0e-01     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0   ]
 [ 2.3e-14     0     7.5e-14  1.6e-13  4.9e-14  5.1e-13  5.7e-14  1.6e-14     0     2.1e-14  4.6e-15     0        0     2.2e-13     0     3.9e-13  3.0e-14  5.2e-14  4.1e-13  2.9e-13     0     3.0e-13     0        0        0        0        0    -1.2e+00     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0   ]
 [ 3.0e-13     0     9.7e-13  2.1e-12  6.3e-13  6.6e-12  7.4e-13  2.0e-13     0     2.8e-13  5.9e-14     0        0     2.9e-12     0     5.1e-12  3.9e-13  6.7e-13  5.3e-12  3.7e-12     0     3.9e-12     0        0        0        0        0        0    -9.8e-01     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0   ]
 [ 3.1e-13     0     9.9e-13  2.1e-12  6.4e-13  6.7e-12  7.6e-13  2.1e-13     0     2.8e-13  6.0e-14     0        0     2.9e-12     0     5.2e-12  4.0e-13  6.9e-13  5.4e-12  3.8e-12     0     4.0e-12     0        0        0        0        0        0        0    -9.5e-02     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0   ]
 [ 1.2e-13     0     3.7e-13  7.9e-13  2.4e-13  2.5e-12  2.8e-13  7.8e-14     0     1.1e-13  2.3e-14     0        0     1.1e-12     0     1.9e-12  1.5e-13  2.6e-13  2.0e-12  1.4e-12     0     1.5e-12     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0    -3.5e+00     0        0        0        0        0        0        0   ]
 [ 4.0e-13     0     1.3e-12  2.7e-12  8.2e-13  8.6e-12  9.7e-13  2.7e-13     0     3.6e-13  7.8e-14     0        0     3.8e-12     0     6.6e-12  5.1e-13  8.8e-13  6.9e-12  4.9e-12     0     5.2e-12     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0    -2.6e-02     0        0        0        0        0        0   ]
 [ 1.3e-11  1.8e-10  4.0e-10  6.2e-10  1.4e-10  7.9e-10  9.4e-11  9.4e-11  1.0e-09  6.8e-11  5.5e-11  9.0e-10  1.5e-10  8.6e-10  1.0e-10  6.0e-10  3.3e-11  1.2e-10  6.9e-10  2.1e-10     0     2.2e-10  1.0e-09  1.0e-09  1.0e-09     0        0        0        0        0        0        0    -4.1e-02     0        0        0        0        0   ]
 [ 2.0e-11  2.8e-10  6.2e-10  9.6e-10  2.1e-10  1.2e-09  1.5e-10  1.4e-10  1.6e-09  1.0e-10  8.5e-11  1.4e-09  2.3e-10  1.3e-09  1.5e-10  9.2e-10  5.1e-11  1.9e-10  1.1e-09  3.2e-10     0     3.4e-10  1.6e-09  1.6e-09  1.6e-09     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0    -2.7e-05     0        0        0        0   ]
 [ 2.0e-14  2.8e-13  6.2e-13  9.5e-13  2.1e-13  1.2e-12  1.4e-13  1.4e-13  1.6e-12  1.0e-13  8.4e-14  1.4e-12  2.3e-13  1.3e-12  1.5e-13  9.1e-13  5.0e-14  1.9e-13  1.0e-12  3.1e-13     0     3.3e-13  1.5e-12  1.6e-12  1.6e-12     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0    -3.5e+00     0        0        0   ]
 [ 3.1e-11  4.2e-10  9.4e-10  1.4e-09  3.2e-10  1.8e-09  2.2e-10  2.2e-10  2.4e-09  1.6e-10  1.3e-10  2.1e-09  3.5e-10  2.0e-09  2.3e-10  1.4e-09  7.6e-11  2.8e-10  1.6e-09  4.8e-10     0     5.0e-10  2.3e-09  2.4e-09  2.4e-09     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0    -4.0e-04     0        0   ]
 [ 2.4e-12  3.3e-11  7.3e-11  1.1e-10  2.5e-11  1.4e-10  1.7e-11  1.7e-11  1.9e-10  1.2e-11  9.9e-12  1.6e-10  2.7e-11  1.6e-10  1.8e-11  1.1e-10  5.9e-12  2.2e-11  1.2e-10  3.7e-11     0     3.9e-11  1.8e-10  1.9e-10  1.9e-10     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0    -7.0e-03     0   ]
 [ 1.6e-11  2.2e-10  4.9e-10  7.6e-10  1.7e-10  9.7e-10  1.1e-10  1.1e-10  1.3e-09  8.3e-11  6.7e-11  1.1e-09  1.8e-10  1.1e-09  1.2e-10  7.3e-10  4.0e-11  1.5e-10  8.4e-10  2.5e-10     0     2.6e-10  1.2e-09  1.3e-09  1.3e-09     0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0    -4.2e-03]]
```

Comment: Can you share how you get `my_dict` ? Why do you use a dictionary to represent a matrix at the first place?

Comment: Could you just create the array once. And then copy it as needed each time. I.e. do the initialization values change? 
I.e. the timings here might also be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50825480

Comment: @expectedAn my_dict is defined once at the beginning of the program. It contains physical data corresponding to material that are then represented in an array form to be able to use a DGESV solver

Comment: @chumbaloo I have no idea why it didn't occur to me before, but I believe you hit it right on. My arrays do change but I believe I can extract a "initial array" that can then be multiplied by a different (but known) variable at each iteration and then my problem becomes (a bit more complex but same idea) "A * f + B", where A and B are initial numpy arrays defined once and f is dependent on the iteration parameters, hence a hugely impactful vectorization. This can be brilliant if it works, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Generally speaking just copying an array will be much faster than the repeated individual read from dict and subsequent write to single location in array. Glad it was useful.

Comment: If you represented `my_dict` as three ndarrays `row, col, val` then conversion would faster (I'm talking about ~100x speedups). Please share the code used to create `my_dict` and `idx`

Comment: you can use `np.ma.masked_array` to put a mask over the zeros and reduce the computation time because AFAIK numpy doesn't compute with masked entries in an array. I don't know what the major chunk of your code is doing, but this may halp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting an answer for those that stumble upon this post.

I got very lucky that actually, my data could be vectorized since I was able to use something like F = Ax + B, with A and B constant numpy arrays, instead of defining F "from scratch" at every step with a modified x like I was doing. The performance boost is immense. The idea of "forcing a way to vectorize" from @chumbaloo is what I ended up using for the bulk of the optimization.

So, if you feel you cannot vectorize but absolutely need to optimize, still try and find a way to vectorize. At least this is my takeaway.

I also used the suggestions given by @tstanisl and @expectedAn, which was to move a dictionary to a numpy array right before using it for intensive lookup calculations, which had a big impact too in another part of my code by allowing me to make some vector calculations instead of a for loop.